# Could Black Holes (theoretically) be used to hold Atoms together?

Tags: black-holes, atoms, subatomic

I've heard that light (in most circumstances) cannot escape a black hole... HOWEVER, what if we made the black hole smaller? (even smaller than a Proton).

So that naturally lead me to wonder... Could small black holes be used to hold Atoms together?

(Yes I am very well aware of that Black Holes are giant, Spacetime warping abominations that destroy everything that enters them).

(Note: If my question is within the realms of plausibility then you can make the Black Holes as small as you want/need).

Sorry if this question is outside the realms of science! (My only knowledge of black holes is that they warp spacetime and they emit Hawking Radiation)

Comment: Note: I am new to this Stack Exchange... So forgive me (or don't) if I come off as uninformed (in physics) or noobish

Comment: What do you mean by hold atoms together? Atoms are already held together by the electrostatic and nuclear forces.

Comment: when I say "hold atoms together" I mean as an addition to those other forces

Comment: Such a small black hole [would evaporate in a short time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation).

Comment: In addition to the Hawking Radiation problem (comment above) and the electric charge problem, there's also a very good chance that there's no mechanism to ever produce black holes that size.   Some people thought shortly after the big bang - maybe, but observations so far imply that's not the case.    It's also likely that such a theoretical black hole would only hold a few atoms close to it, it would be too dense to build anything out of.   The size of a nucleus but the mass trillions of times greater,  the density would crush anything if there was any size to such an object.

Comment: Thanks everyone! asking one question actually helped me learn about black holes!

Answer (score 1):

Two more points.

Once inside BHs horizons the atoms, or anything else, probably loose their identity; classically they get crushed in the singularity inside the BH. Quantum gravity, if we ever have an accepted theory, may say that some quantum or stringy or Planckian entity survives, but it won't be atoms.

So atoms won't survive inside BHs. What about nearby outside? If far enough it'll just be like any other gravitational attracting object, and maybe they'll orbit around it. But so may other things with which they will collide and probably break up. If close to the horizon the gravity tidal force will be strong and probably will break them apart. Also with collisions with other objects. Near BHs large amounts of gas and particles and radiation will orbit very fast and mix it all up, and radiate a bunch of radiation.

The next thing, is, can you form small BHs that could have been formed form a few atoms? No, but micro BHs could have been formed in the early moments after the Big Bang, in very very dense quantum soup (maybe a bunch of quarks, gluons, electrons and photons). They could have been formed at multiple mass scales, it's somewhat uncertain but smaller masses are more likely than larger ones. Still, if too small they would have evaporated (through Hawking radiation) by now. If $10^{11}$ kg (say an asteroid) or more they would still be around today. There limits on how many there could be around now for the different masses, based on observations of what has not been seen (eg, from gamma ray and other observations). The least limited number for sizes from observations seem to be about the mass of the earth. But none have been observed as of now, and there could still be smaller ones

Just pointing this out because they could still exist, and have dragged in material, including some atoms. Just those are not atoms or molecules any more. This may not be any of what you're looking for, but it's something about BHs that are not necessarily the huge astronomical eat it all monsters you hear about. It is calculated that a small enough BH will go through the earth undetected (if traveling very fast), and a little larger we could detect some acoustic signals. None have been detected form any of those.

See about micro BHs, and also primordial BHs at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole

Comment: Also, fundamental particles have too high of an angular momentum to mass ratio to ever be black holes.  They are predicted to be naked singularities.

Comment: Good point. Same thing for charged particles?

Comment: Yes, the charge is too large for most of them too, but I think the angular momentum problem is worse.

Comment: Why worse? Same problem, you can't get rid of charge.

Comment: worse because $a/M > q/M$ for most fundamental particles.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had not calculated or noticed that before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how nor why. Atoms are "held together" by the strong nuclear interaction, in the nucleus, this interaction keeps the quarks together to form hadrons such as protons and neutrons. On a scale of 1 fm it also serves to mediate the interaction between those hadrons, protons and neutrons. Besides that, atoms are also held together by the electromagnetic interaction between protons and electrons.

Comment: That actually cleared up alot! (I still wish I got an answer involving black holes though). But I'll take what I can get! Thanks QuantumSerbian!

Comment: Microscopic black holes are thought to exist but they have a very short "life" span. So I would say no, they wouldn't be able to hold together an atom.